# Auto assign Id based on Name upon Trigger

Tags: trigger

The scenario I have MyObject that has lookup field Account.The issue is user can put Name instead of Id in Account field and upload using Data Import Wizard.The requirement is to automatically assign the Id based on the Name that inserted by the user.If user key in 'ABC', the code should be intelligent enough to pick Id from Account based on 'ABC', the result may vary but it will take the first one.

I wrote trigger but how to tie it back to MyObject after it gets the result?

```
trigger MyObject_Trg on MyObject__c (before update,before insert){

  Set<String> setAccountNames = new Set<String>();
  for(MyObject__c o : Trigger.New){
        ID someId;
        String someString=o.Account__c;
        Boolean isValidId = true;
        try {someId = (ID) someString;}
        catch (Exception e) {isValidId = false;}

        if(!isValidId && o.Account!=null){

          setAccountNames.add(o.Account__c+'%')



        }
   }

   //run query to retrieve the Account Id
    List<Account> lsAccount = [Select Id,Name from Account where  Name like :setAccountNames];

    //how to assign back the Id to MyObject__c?


}
```

Also please advise if there any proper way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Unidha try this code

```
Set<Id> setAccountNames = new Set<Id>();
for(MyObject__c o : Trigger.New){
    ID someId;
    String someString=o.Account__c;
    Boolean isValidId = true;
    try {someId = (ID) someString;}
    catch (Exception e) {isValidId = false;}

    if(!isValidId && o.Account!=null){
      setAccountNames.add(o.Account__c+'%');
    }
}


List<Account> lsAccount = [Select Id,Name from Account where  Name like :setAccountNames];

Map<String, Id> mapAccountId= new map<String, Id>();

for(Account ls: lsAccount){
    mapAccountId.put(ls.name, ls.id);
}

for(MyObject__c o : Trigger.New){
    if(mapAccountId.containsKey(o.Account__c)){
        o.Account__c = mapAccountId.get(o.Account__c);
    }
}
```

There is the simple logic behind this. 
All you have to do is put all account 
name as a key and id as a value. 
then retraverse the Trigger.new() and set respective values.

Comment: Note that setAccountNames contain '%' at behind , will this impact the result ?

Comment: Is there going to be incomplete account Name. Like If account Name is "Arshad" so it may be"Arsh".

Comment: Yes, if the user can input not exact name such Arsh , the code must try to assign with the similar name.Other example, user input 'ABC' , the code may assign it to 'ABC Bank' ;the data that it retrieve from the wildcard.

Comment: there could be hundreds of possibilities so how you are gonna compare them.